# .jsp file not running through HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a file `hello.jsp`. Its working fine in tomcat when I type `localhost:8080/hello.jsp` in the url tab of the browser.

However when I try to call the file from html like this:

```
<form action="hello.jsp">
```

I get the error

> "Your file was not found ,It may have been moved or deleted"

and no page is loaded. How can I run my file through HTML page. I am having same problem with servlet too.

Comment: Is the HTML page also in the same tomcat?

Comment: Is the html file in the same directory as the hello.jsp file?

Comment: If I put jsp file in the same directory, it works as a plain html file. Java code does not get executed, but printed as it is.

Comment: @ShubhamKhare actually you should try it the other way round: put the html-page into the same directory as your jsp.

Comment: @piet tried that too, jsp file runs as plain html file. Why is my tomcat not invoked in that case.

Comment: To run java code you must run the file under Tomcat server @ShubhamKhare

Comment: Did you call the html-page using `localhost:8080/pagename.html`?

Comment: What bothers me is that there is no App name in your url. It should look like **localhost:8080/ProjectName/PageName.jsp** If you've put the jsp file into the your tomcat directory without any projet, I don't know if it will be compile and interpreted (like PHP)

Comment: Thank you @piet.t. It worked. You could have posted that as an answer. Anyways , Thanks!!